# How to add same rank to groups if data contains one different column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sample dataset:

```sql
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:00:00' as start_time, 1 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:01:00' as start_time, 1 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:05:00' as start_time, 1 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:10:00' as start_time, 2 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:15:00' as start_time, 2 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:20:00' as start_time, 2 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:25:00' as start_time, 3 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:30:00' as start_time, 3 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-03 02:00:00' as start_time, 3 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-03 02:00:45' as start_time, 4 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-03 02:15:00' as start_time, 4 as flag
union all
select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-03 09:20:00' as start_time, 4 as flag;
```

**Script**

```sql
select a.num0
     , a.num1
     , a.start_time
     , a.flag as expected_value
     , rank() over (partition by a.num1 order by start_time) as flag2
from test_01 as a
order by a.start_time;
```

The `flag` (actually counter) column I've created to show what value is expected in `flag 2` column.
Task - if consecutive values of column `num1` is same - so this group  of rows should have same flag (counter). `num0` - same for all dataset rows. As You see in dataset between same column values can be another same values, so in that case it another group and it should have another flag that by one bigger that previous `flag` (counter) and so on for next groups even if they contains same values for `num1` column

Unfortunately due to `start_time` column, using `Oracle rank` is not possible.

Comment: Your sample data is not valid in Oracle (before Oracle 23) as you are missing a `FROM` clause in all the `SELECT`s and your script is not valid syntax as Oracle does not allow `AS` before a table alias. Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flag is the count of num1 changes:

```
with data(num0, num1, start_time, flag) as (
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:00:00' as start_time, 1 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:01:00' as start_time, 1 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:05:00' as start_time, 1 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:10:00' as start_time, 2 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:15:00' as start_time, 2 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:20:00' as start_time, 2 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:25:00' as start_time, 3 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-01 00:30:00' as start_time, 3 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000001' as num1, '2023-01-03 02:00:00' as start_time, 3 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-03 02:00:45' as start_time, 4 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-03 02:15:00' as start_time, 4 as flag FROM dual
    union all
    select '1000000000000' as num0, '2000002' as num1, '2023-01-03 09:20:00' as start_time, 4 as flag FROM dual
)
SELECT num0, num1, start_time, flag,
    sum(change) OVER(ORDER BY start_time) AS flag2
FROM (
    SELECT num0, num1, start_time, flag,
    decode(num1, lag(num1) over(ORDER BY start_time), 0,1) AS change
    FROM DATA 
)
ORDER BY start_time
;
```

Comment: Hi! This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT num0
     , num1
     , start_time
     , flag as expected_value
     , flag2
FROM   test_01
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY start_time
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS flag2
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (same_num1+)
  DEFINE same_num1 AS FIRST(num1) = num1
)
ORDER BY start_time;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_01 (num0, num1, start_time, flag) AS
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000001', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000001', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:01:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000001', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:05:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000002', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:10:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000002', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:15:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000002', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:20:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000001', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:25:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000001', DATE '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL '00:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000001', DATE '2023-01-03' + INTERVAL '02:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000002', DATE '2023-01-03' + INTERVAL '02:00:45' HOUR TO SECOND, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000002', DATE '2023-01-03' + INTERVAL '02:15:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1000000000000', '2000002', DATE '2023-01-03' + INTERVAL '09:20:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 4 FROM DUAL ;
```

Outputs:

| NUM0 | NUM1 | START_TIME | EXPECTED_VALUE | FLAG2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000000000000 | 2000001 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000001 | 2023-01-01 00:01:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000001 | 2023-01-01 00:05:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000002 | 2023-01-01 00:10:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000002 | 2023-01-01 00:15:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000002 | 2023-01-01 00:20:00 | 2 | 2 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000001 | 2023-01-01 00:25:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000001 | 2023-01-01 00:30:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000001 | 2023-01-03 02:00:00 | 3 | 3 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000002 | 2023-01-03 02:00:45 | 4 | 4 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000002 | 2023-01-03 02:15:00 | 4 | 4 |
| 1000000000000 | 2000002 | 2023-01-03 09:20:00 | 4 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4H1zDgNz)